# SpringBootTest giving 404 error, but curl succeeds

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a `@SpringBootApplication` with a `@Component` with some `@GET` and `@POST` methods. I am able to successfully launch the application and use curl on the get and post methods. However, when I try to run a `@SpringBootTest`, my request gives a 404 error.

Here's the Component class:

```
@Path("/")
@Component
public class TestComp {

    @Path("test")
    @GET
    public String test() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

And here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andDo(print());
    }

}
```

Is there some sort of configuration I need to be doing on the `SpringBootApplication`? Is my uri in `get("/test")` just wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, `MockMvc` can't be used with `Jersey`, which I'm using. If anyone stumbles upon this, here's an [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey) of unit testing with Jersey.

Comment: try using `WebTestClient` instead of using mockMVC, which is the recommended way according to the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I ended up using `TestRestTemplate`, is that just as good? If not, what's the benefit of `WebTestClient` instead?

Comment: spring has deprecated RestTemplate and have plans on removing it in future versions mainly because RestTemplate is blocking while WebClient is non-blocking

Comment: @ThomasAndolf well I'd love to, but I get an error from `@Autowired` when I use `WebTestClient`, so I guess I'm sticking with TestRestTemplate for now :/

Comment: if you read the documentation it says `This setup requires spring-webflux on the classpath`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thank you very much! I was having trouble with that, I should read documentation more carefully...